# Advice for single page Module?

Tags: angularjs

I just wanted some clarification on my idea when I implement. Currently the user will login or register and then be presented with a dashboard style site that will handle things such as uploading to database/via API and displaying or editing database results. With this idea is angular designed to implement this entire structure as a single module? Or should it be separated eg, login module and dashboard module?

Also another query is a better structured angular app one that reduces the amount of inline directives. Eg ng-something?

I have been following the tutorial via w3schools but I don't think this resource covers all of it or is it just that simple? All my controllers and services or directives will be in their respective files.

Am I thinking about Angular the correct way? Would this framework support large user interaction and such? Thanks

Comment: Its a pretty good video that explains how token based authentication works with a server protected backend. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDb_GANDR8U

Answer (score 0):

You should try to separate parts of your application into modules/submodules. This way you gain (at least) two things:

- You will be able to unit test each module in separation
- The modules list acts as a "map" of application's functionality

Take a look at this example:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngRoute',
        'myApp.shared',
        'myApp.dashboard',
        'myApp.users'
    ]);
```

Btw. you can gain a lot of understanding about **not only how but also why** to approach certain aspects of Angular architecture by reading through one of available styleguides, like https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#modules or https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide